# localrepo throws "Could not locate ... " error when I try to use it

Tags: emacs, clojure, leiningen

I'm using lein 1.7.1 on a ubuntu machine. I've added `localrepo` by including 
`:dev-dependencies [[lein-localrepo "0.3"]]` 
to my project.clj file. `lein deps` runs fine but using `localrepo` like in `lein localrepo coords example.jar` throws me a nasty error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate leiningen/core/main__init.class or leiningen/core/main.clj on classpath:  (localrepo.clj:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5441)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5416)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:5858)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:340)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:331)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:409)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:381)
at clojure.core$load$fn__4519.invoke(core.clj:4915)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:4914)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:4729)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:4766)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:4800)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:4881)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at leiningen.core$resolve_task.invoke(core.clj:208)
at leiningen.core$apply_task.invoke(core.clj:258)
at leiningen.core$_main.doInvoke(core.clj:329)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
at leiningen.core$_main.invoke(core.clj:332)
at user$eval42.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5425)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5392)
at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2382)
at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:235)
at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:254)
at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:270)
at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:354)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512)
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:385)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:185)
at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:482)
at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate leiningen/core/main__init.class or leiningen/core/main.clj on classpath: 
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:381)
at clojure.core$load$fn__4519.invoke(core.clj:4915)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:4914)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:4729)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:4766)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:4800)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:4881)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:551)
at leiningen.localrepo$eval68$loading__4414__auto____69.invoke(localrepo.clj:1)
at leiningen.localrepo$eval68.invoke(localrepo.clj:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5425)
... 37 more
```

I've searched this error on the web, but can't find any reference to it or any viable solutions. How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you're using version 0.3 of the lein-localrepo plugin.  I suspect a newer version is being picked up.  Version 0.3 [doesn't make reference](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-localrepo/blob/v0.3/src/leiningen/localrepo.clj) to `leiningen.core.main` whereas [0.4 or better does](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-localrepo/blob/master/src/leiningen/localrepo.clj#L3).  If you manage to get the right plugin installed, I bet it will work fine.